# No page fault generated by accesses to non-present page 0

Tags: c, x86, paging, osdev

I have a working initial page map setup and exception handler in my i386 kernel, and for the most part everything is going smoothly, but in testing page fault conditions I noticed that accesses to anywhere in page 0 do not trigger a page fault, even though that page is unmapped and has the 'present' bit cleared. This is odd because accessing any other unmapped page does generate the expected page fault, just not page 0. It would be nice for accesses here to cause an exception so that the kernel will panic if future buggy code ends up dereferencing a null pointer. I'm seeing this behavior on both QEMU and a real x86 PC, and I can't find any indication of this being normal behavior, so I must be doing *something* wrong.

Here's my page map initialization code. Currently the kernel's code and data are identity-mapped starting at 0x100000.

```
extern uint32_t *page_directory;
extern uint32_t *page_table;

// set by linker script
extern void *kernel_code_end;
extern void *kernel_end;

void paging_init()
{
    uint32_t i, addr;
    uint8_t flags;

    memset(page_directory, 0, 4096);
    memset(page_table, 0, 4096);

    for (i = 256; i < 1024; i++) {
        addr = 4096 * i;
        if (addr > (uint32_t) &kernel_end)
            break;

        if (addr < (uint32_t) &kernel_code_end)
            flags = 0x1; // mark kernel code read-only
        else
            flags = 0x3;
        page_table[i] = addr | flags;
    }

    page_table[255] = 0xb8000 | 0x3; // map VGA text memory to 0xff000
    page_directory[0] = (uint32_t) page_table | 0x3;

    asm("movl %0, %%eax" : : "a" (page_directory));
    asm("movl %eax, %cr3");
    asm("movl %cr0, %eax");
    asm("orl $0x80010000, %eax");
    asm("movl %eax, %cr0");
}
```

As an example of the behavior I'm seeing, I put this memory dump loop at the end of the kernel's main function:

```
for (int i = 0x000000; i < 0x100000; i += 4)
    kprintf("%x: %x\n", i, *((uint32_t*) i));
```

It's able to dump the entirety of page 0, addresses 0x0000 through 0x0fff, but finally generates a page fault as soon as it reaches 0x1000.

Comment: paging_init is already 32 bit code right? I don't see a tlb flush instruction after assigning to cr0. If it weren't for the fact it's still not working in qemu I'd assume that's the problem.

Comment: Yep, this is in 32-bit mode after booting from grub. I thought the write to cr3 itself flushed the TLB?

Comment: I'm used to seeing invalpg but osdev says you are right.

Comment: You might double check the assembly that your loop generates.  The compiler might have figured out that it's a null pointer dereference, hence undefined behavior, and "optimized" it in a peculiar way.  They're known to do things like that.

Comment: Your inline asm is problematic, by the way.  You read and write `rax` which is not properly declared as an input/output register; the compiler can mess with its value between asm statements, and might keep important data there.  And since you don't have `memory` clobbers, the compiler could also reorder the asm before the code that updates the page table.

Comment: In this case the output assembly is fine, but I suppose I got lucky. Still getting used to the asm macro's obscure usage, so thanks for the tips.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind! I didn't realize that, like the symbols kernel_end and kernel_code_end that were defined in the linker script, page_table and page_directory -- defined in an external assembly file as 4k buffers within the bss segment -- are also linked to this C file as if they're located *at* that buffer rather than pointing to it. This means that they were actually uninitialized and pointing to address 0, so page 0 was set up to be both the page directory and page table! This is how page 0 ended up mapped into the valid virtual address space.

I modified the paging initialization function as such and now everything works as expected:

```
extern uint32_t *page_directory;
extern uint32_t *page_table;

// set by linker script
extern void *kernel_code_end;
extern void *kernel_end;

static void paging_init()
{
    uint32_t *pdir = (uint32_t*) &page_directory;
    uint32_t *ptab = (uint32_t*) &page_table;

    uint32_t i, addr;
    uint8_t flags;

    memset(pdir, 0, 4096);
    memset(ptab, 0, 4096);

    for (i = 256; i < 1024; i++) {
        addr = 4096 * i;
        if (addr > (uint32_t) &kernel_end)
            break;

        if (addr < (uint32_t) &kernel_code_end)
            flags = 0x1; // mark kernel code read-only
        else
            flags = 0x3;
        ptab[i] = addr | flags;
    }

    ptab[255] = 0xb8000 | 0x3; // map VGA text memory to 0xff000
    pdir[0] = (uint32_t) ptab | 0x3;

    asm("movl %0, %%eax" : : "a" (pdir));
    asm("movl %eax, %cr3");
    asm("movl %cr0, %eax");
    asm("orl $0x80010000, %eax");
    asm("movl %eax, %cr0");
}
```

Comment: A common trick here is to declare `extern uint32_t page_directory[];` so that array-pointer decay lets you simply write `page_directory[0]`, etc.

Comment: That inline asm is unsafe.  You aren't telling the compiler about writing to EAX, and you depend on EAX keeping its value between asm statements.  Also, the `mov` instruction in `asm("movl %0, %%eax" : : "a" (pdir));`  is pointless; you've already asked the compiler to have it in EAX, so it will compile to `mov %eax, %eax` when it fills in the template.  The real problem is that after this code, the compiler can assume that EAX holds `pdir` because it put it there as a read-only input, and the later statements were GNU C Basic Asm (which you should never use except in a `naked` function)

Comment: https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/ConvertBasicAsmToExtended

Comment: Thanks for the tips, I admit I only learned the bare minimum about the (far more complicated than I expected) asm macro to do these few lines, but I'll read more about it and rewrite this part. I guess I got lucky that it still works, but you're right about that redundant `mov %eax, %eax` getting generated.

Comment: @NateEldredge Thanks for that! I didn't know that would be treated differently from the pointer types I already had. Switched to this and it works.